# AngularJS + Select2 (Multiple - Tags) - sometimes show tags others not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tags, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using AngularJS + select2 (not ui-select).

Then in my view I have:

```
<select 
name="rubros" 
id="rubros" 
class="select2 form-control"
ng-model="vm.comercio.tags" 
ng-options="rubro.nombre for rubro in vm.rubros track by rubro.id"
multiple>
</select>
```

As you can see , the select is bind to a variable called "comercio.tags", that is an array of objects.

Well, here is the funny thing: the tags are displayed sometimes, and sometimes they don't. Even though the binding is working.

And the behavior is random; I can press F5 in my browser and the error appear and goes randomly.

Please take a look at the images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The tags are retrieved by a get request ($http).

I don't know what is going on here. Because the behavior is randomly reproduced.

Update:

Add code requested by helper member

```
//controller initialization before this

var scope = this;

var id = $routeParams.id;   //the ID of the commerce/store I want to edit (preload) in the page

//variable where I save the retrievedcommerce/store
scope.comercio = {
    tags:[]
};

/*
    HTTP request to retrieve the commerce/store with "id"
    The model retrieved has a tags attribute that is correctly filled (as you can see in the images, 
    in the input on top of the select2, I used to debug)
*/

$http.get("http://localhost:8000/api/comercio/" + id).then(function (response) {

    scope.comercio = response.data.model;

},
function (response) {

    scope.comercio = null;

});

//other controllers instructions and declarations
```

Comment: Because AngularJS isn't controlling the rendering, you might run into random timing issues caused by the variable time it takes for the request to come back? Can you show $http code?

Comment: Note that jQuery is not part of AngularJS digest cycle. You might need to wrap it in a directive with `$timeout` or `$apply`. (Like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906168/how-to-default-select2-in-angularjs))

Comment: @Protozoid , I just added the code

Comment: @AlekseySolovey, I am taking  alook at it, be right back

Comment: Thanks a lot people , finally I understood the reason of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people suggested , the reason of this issue is because select2 is a jQuery plugin and we have to attach it to the angular "refresh"/compile/digest/watch ... cycle .. in other words, we need to attach select2 to the angularJS app lifecycle.

How do we do it ? using a directive. The official documentation is really extensive but you can appreciate the solution with this little piece of code.

```
app.directive("appSelect2", function($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            jQuery(element).select2();

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    element.trigger('change.select2');
                }, 100);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

With this directive , and adding the "app-select2" attribute to the select2 input declared in your html ... it works perfectly.

I appreciate the help provided very much, thanks a lot.